# Согласование слова "стереотип"

Tags: согласование, орфоэпия

Здравствуйте!

У меня возник вопрос о (если я правильно выражаюсь) грамматическом согласовании со словом "стереотип". К примеру, стереотип о наследовании привилегий или стереотип наследования... Как правильно, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2):

Слово *стереотип* управляет (это именно управление, а не согласование) формой родительного падежа. Так что корректный вариант: *стереотип наследования*.